# Substracting two cells in excel and dividing by the other one

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet

I have my data in A and B cells. Let A_i be the i-th entry in the A columns and the same for B_i. My formula for columns C would be (A_i - A_(i+1))/B_i. How can I do that in Excel?

Comment: This question belongs on SuperUser.com, because it is about basic functionality of Excel. If you are not aware how cell references adjust when a formula is copied down, then you may want to do a beginner's course in Excel instead of asking on a site geared at programmers.

Answer (score 0):

Since the rows and columns in Excel (and all other spreadsheets) are referenced by an **cell address** which is always written with the *column* letter followed by the *row* number, calculations in Excel should always be written by using these cell addresses.

The address for the first cell at the top of the worksheet is **A1**, the one under it is **A2**, and the one beside **A1** is **B1**.

Got that? You might already know that, but others coming here might not.

I assume you mean something like this:
[image]

Let me know if you have any questions and I'll try to respond.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I have 1000 entries so doing this like that would be highly impractical (I would have to do this for every single one). That's why I labeled my cells by A_i to do it for every single one for example by dragging. But I don't know how to affect all my cells. So first entry would be (A1-A2)/B1, second one (A2-A3)/B2 etc

Comment: Without using VBA to code it, you can use the End key on your keyboard along with the shift key. Another way is just copy the first equation, select all 999 other cells, and then choose Paste. It works automatically. Is that the problem you were having?